# How can I tell which mysql user edited a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have a database with multiple users who have access to view/edit in phpMyAdmin.

A given row was edited by one of the users through phpMyAdmin. Is there a way for me to know which user made the edit?

NOTE: We have not touched the row since that specific edit

Comment: No. If you want to know information like this, you need to explicitly store the user's id. I doubt that you can do this with PHPMyAdmin. But, I may be mistaken.

Comment: Might not help your current predicament, but if you're looking to capture this information in the future, you might want to look into keeping a [binary log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html) or [query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html)

Comment: @e_i_pi, IIRC, the binary log does not record the user.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, I haven't used them myself (I prefer MSSQL and PostgreSQL), but any logging can help form a paper trail between applications, which can lead to inferring or deducing who/what/when/how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible to add a `TRIGGER` that captures info with `USER()`.

But this would mean that each user has to connect separately when using phpmyadmin, and not use some common login.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely too late to get information about which mysql user executed a change previously.

If you happened to have the slow query log enabled when the change occurred, you might have a record of which mysql user executed the change.

There's also an optional audit plugin feature for some MySQL instances, but since this requires installing a third-party plugin, and all the audit plugin implementations I know of are not easy to manage, it's almost certainly the case that you don't have this.

In either case, the best you could hope for is to know which mysql user executed the change.

But phpmyadmin is usually configured to connect as one mysql user, regardless of which human is operating it. So even if you had logging,  this mysql user is a shared user, it would be inconclusive which human being did the action.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd have to disagree about the part where you say phpMyAdmin is usually configured to use a shared account. This is a function of the database administrator, not phpMyAdmin; all the databases I maintain or use regularly have individual accounts for each user rather than shared access. Maybe I'm just spoiled by good policies, and this detail shouldn't take anything away from the rest of your great answer, but I did want to chime in and add my two cents about it.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch, you don't think that most phpMyAdmin installations use **Config Authentication Mode** hard-coding one user/password in `config.inc.php` so that anyone who can open phpMyAdmin in their browser is automatically connected to MySQL?

Comment: I hope not, but I admit that the human capacity to do things that's a bad idea continually exceeds my expectations. That's not the default, so someone would have to willingly change it, and then they'd be opening up their database for anyone who can guess their IP address.

Comment: It might be running on an intranet host, so it's not accessible to the external network. So the risk is low that an outside person can access their database. But the problem the OP asked about was to identify which person, who presumably all have authorized access, executed a specific change. If people share a MySQL login (by auth_type config or even if they use default auth_type but share a login), then the information about which human user performed a given change is lost.